# Migrate to rails 3 & encoding

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, rails-3-upgrade

After migrate to Rails 3.0.10, I got broke encoding text on page.

I got "Ð‘ÐµÐ³ Ð±ÐµÐ³ Ð±ÐµÐ³" instead "Бег бег бег". Other text on page looks good.

This text came from DB and have "CP1252" encoding. I am using MYSQL.

I try add "encoding: utf8" param in my database.yml file, but nothing has improved.

I had no such problems in Rails 2 with this text.

Comment: I'm no expert in character-encoding issues - I just have a lot of them :)  But it might help if you could run a rails console, and show a concise script of what happens when you try to access the data and display the string and it's encoding (string.encoding).